# PolyBase on SQL Server 2019: IBM DB2 External tables

Tags: sql-server, db2, database-administration, db2-luw, sql-server-2019

I need to make the data from the DB2 10.5 database available as an external table on a PolyBase enabled SQL Server 2019 instance and running into a problem...

In DB2 version 11.1 IBM added the LIMIT clause (LIMIT )
In DB2 version 10.5 IBM was still using the FETCH clause (FETCH FIRST  ROWS ONLY)

SQL server is miss translating a T-SQL TOP clause into LIMIT instead of the FETCH that this database requires.

Has anyone run into this issue before? If so does anyone have a workaround for this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the Db2 server (or can request changes on it) you can use the Db2 [compatibility feature](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html).

Set the registry variable `DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR`:

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS
```

and restart the instance. It will make Db2 recognize `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses. Setting just this bit should not affect other behaviour of the Db2 server.